# D3.js Hierarchical Edge Bundling, how do i change the color of a text group?

Tags: javascript, css, json, d3.js

So i took a code from d3.js and im playing with it, but i dont fully understand de json and js connection and i want to change the color of a certain text group, for example the flare.analytics group

i took the code from here, it includes the json code: https://gist.github.com/mbostock/7607999

Ill be showing the javascript down below.

thanks in advance.

```
var diameter = 960,
    radius = diameter / 2,
    innerRadius = radius - 120;
var cluster = d3.cluster()
    .size([360, innerRadius]);
var line = d3.radialLine()
    .curve(d3.curveBundle.beta(0.85))
    .radius(function(d) { return d.y; })
    .angle(function(d) { return d.x / 180 * Math.PI; });
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", diameter)
    .attr("height", diameter)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");
var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link"),
    node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node");
d3.json("flare.json", function(error, classes) {
  if (error) throw error;
  var root = packageHierarchy(classes)
      .sum(function(d) { return d.size; });
  cluster(root);
  link = link
    .data(packageImports(root.leaves()))
    .enter().append("path")
      .each(function(d) { d.source = d[0], d.target = d[d.length - 1]; })
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", line);
  node = node
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("dy", "0.31em")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.y + 8) + ",0)" + (d.x < 180 ? "" : "rotate(180)"); })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.key; })
      .on("mouseover", mouseovered)
      .on("mouseout", mouseouted);
});
function mouseovered(d) {
  node
      .each(function(n) { n.target = n.source = false; });
  link
      .classed("link--target", function(l) { if (l.target === d) return l.source.source = true; })
      .classed("link--source", function(l) { if (l.source === d) return l.target.target = true; })
    .filter(function(l) { return l.target === d || l.source === d; })
      .raise();
  node
      .classed("node--target", function(n) { return n.target; })
      .classed("node--source", function(n) { return n.source; });
}
function mouseouted(d) {
  link
      .classed("link--target", false)
      .classed("link--source", false);
  node
      .classed("node--target", false)
      .classed("node--source", false);
}
// Lazily construct the package hierarchy from class names.
function packageHierarchy(classes) {
  var map = {};
  function find(name, data) {
    var node = map[name], i;
    if (!node) {
      node = map[name] = data || {name: name, children: []};
      if (name.length) {
        node.parent = find(name.substring(0, i = name.lastIndexOf(".")));
        node.parent.children.push(node);
        node.key = name.substring(i + 1);
      }
    }
    return node;
  }
  classes.forEach(function(d) {
    find(d.name, d);
  });
  return d3.hierarchy(map[""]);
}
// Return a list of imports for the given array of nodes.
function packageImports(nodes) {
  var map = {},
      imports = [];
  // Compute a map from name to node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    map[d.data.name] = d;
  });
  // For each import, construct a link from the source to target 
node.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    if (d.data.imports) d.data.imports.forEach(function(i) {
      imports.push(map[d.data.name].path(map[i]));
    });
  });
  return imports;
}
```

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mdaui.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the color of text from the data, You need  pass a function to analyze the data for each node and return the specific color that you need.

In this case when the text node is appended:

```js
node = node
    .data(root.leaves())
    .enter().append("text")
      .attr("class", "node")

      // SETING CONDICIONAL FILL FOR TEXT
       .style("fill", function(d){
          // if name of node has 'flare.analytics' return red, if not '#000000' 
          if (d.data.name.indexOf('flare.analytics') > -1) return '#ff0000';
          return '#000000';
       })

      .attr("dy", "0.31em")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "rotate(" + (d.x - 90) + ")translate(" + (d.y + 8) + ",0)" + (d.x < 180 ? "" : "rotate(180)"); })
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.x < 180 ? "start" : "end"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.data.key; })
      .on("mouseover", mouseovered)
      .on("mouseout", mouseouted);
```